# Finite theory with no finite model

Tags: model-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{L}=\{f\}$, where $f$ is a unary function symbol. My question is: show that there is a finite $\mathcal{L}$-theory with no finite model?

I think that I can interpret $f$ as  successor function and the theory be the $Th(\mathbb Z ,s)$.  Is my answer true?

Comment: Presumably you want the theory to be consistent, or else this is rather trivial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The emphasis is **finite** theory, though; $Th(\mathbb{Z}, s)$ consists of infinitely many sentences! So you need to pick out *finitely many* sentences which already force the structure to be infinite.

HINT: think about surjections and injections - what's a property infinite sets have, about these types of functions, which finite sets don't?

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the following statements about $f$, then any model of the conjunction of these sentences must be infinite.

- $f$ is injective.
- $f$ is not surjective.